# Populate UITableView with calendar days

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, calendar

I have this probably simple for most of you question.
I want to populate my uitableview with dates starting from today.
What is the best way to make it. I am kind of new to iOS, and I don't want to use datetimepicker. Please, give me any idea where to start.

`UITableView` should look like this:

[image: Table view should look like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make this:

I created array of dates and populated UITableViewCells with that array.
I used dateByAddingUnit to access yesterday's date, date of 2 days ago, and so on:

```
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"
    let today = formatter.stringFromDate(nextDate)
    dateArray = [today]

    for _ in 1...6 {
        previousDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, value: -1, toDate: nextDate, options: [])!
        nextDate = previousDate
        let previous = formatter.stringFromDate(previousDate)
        dateArray.append(previous)
    }
```

and populated the UITableView:

```
    cell.dateLabel.text = dateArray[indexPath.row]
```